# Why doesn't my tk.Toplevel(window) window appear in my pyinstaller-generated exe without a console?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

i have a problem with pyinstaller,when i generate the exe file with console that it works( can pop up the tk.Toplevel(window) ),but it does not work when the exe with non console( can not pop up the tk.Toplevel(window) -->pyinstaller -F -w  xxx.py    ).Is there any way for me to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import time
from IPython.display import display
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from pandastable import Table


def run():
    ticker = ticker_entry.get()
    start_date = start_date_entry.get()
    end_date = end_date_entry.get()
    period = int(period_entry.get())

    start_date = f"{start_date}"
    end_date = f"{end_date}"
    ticker = f"{ticker}"
    df = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    df['20_day_high'] = df['High'].rolling(window=20, closed="left").max()
    df['10_day_low'] = df['Low'].rolling(window=10, closed="left").min()
    df['buy_signal'] = df['Close'] > df['20_day_high']
    df['sell_signal'] = df['Close'] < df['10_day_low']
    col_name = df.columns.tolist()
    col_name.insert(col_name.index('sell_signal') + 1, 'Long Vol')
    col_name.insert(col_name.index('Long Vol') + 1, 'Short Vol')
    col_name.insert(col_name.index('Short Vol') + 1, 'Day Vol(E+H)')
    col_name.insert(col_name.index('Day Vol(E+H)') + 1, 'Net Volume')
    col_name.insert(col_name.index('Net Volume') + 1, 'Ma')
    df = df.reindex(columns=col_name)

    position = 0
    value = 0
    capital = 10000
    trade_records = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        #
        buy_signal = row['Close'] > row['20_day_high']
        sell_signal = row['Close'] < row['10_day_low']

        if position == 0 and buy_signal:
            position = 1  
            buy_price = row['Close']
            units = float(capital / buy_price)
            value = units * buy_price
            trade_records.append((i, 'Buy', row['Close'], units, value))

        if position == 1 and sell_signal:
            position = 0  
            sell_price = row['Close']
            capital = float(units * sell_price)
            value = capital
            trade_records.append((i, 'Sell', row['Close'], units, value))

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M")

    results = pd.DataFrame(trade_records, columns=['Date', 'Trade', 'Price', 'Units', 'Value'])
    results['Value'] = results['Value'].fillna(0)
    results['PnL'] = results['Value'].diff() * 1
    results['PnL'] = results['PnL'].round(2)
    total_pnl = results['PnL'].sum()
    total_row = pd.DataFrame([['Total PNL', '', '', '', '', total_pnl]], columns=results.columns)
    results = pd.concat([total_row, results]).reset_index(drop=True)

    table_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    table_window.title
    table_window.geometry("800x600")


    table_frame = tk.Frame(table_window)
    table_frame.pack(pady=10)


    table = Table(table_frame, dataframe=results)
    table.show()
    table.autoResizeColumns()



window = tk.Tk()
window.title("UI")


ticker_label = tk.Label(window, text="STOCK: like: NVDA")
ticker_label.pack()
ticker_entry = tk.Entry(window)
ticker_entry.pack()

start_date_label = tk.Label(window, text="START DATE: YYYY-MM-DD")
start_date_label.pack()
start_date_entry = tk.Entry(window)
start_date_entry.pack()

end_date_label = tk.Label(window, text="END DATE: YYYY-MM-DD")
end_date_label.pack()
end_date_entry = tk.Entry(window)
end_date_entry.pack()

period_label = tk.Label(window, text="PERIOD:5")
period_label.pack()
period_entry = tk.Entry(window)
period_entry.pack()


run_button = tk.Button(window, text="RUN", command=run)
run_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

i have tried pyinstaller --nonconsole or -w or windowed,but not work